# Does ajax call made from the js file included in HTML Page Of Android web view faces CORS Issue?

Tags: android, ajax, cors, android-webview

We are developing the hybrid Android app with web view we have `index.js` and we are making AJAX call through js.
When I open HTML page (which is having above `index.js` in the browser it gives CORS issue.

My question: If I load same HTML page in android web view will it give same CORS issue?

We are calling one service through AJAX call which returns JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem I didn't got any more CORS issues when I send my request like this:

```
var getAJAXDATAWITHCORSPROBLEMS = function () {
var url = URL_WHERE_YOU_WANT_TO_GET_DATA_FROM;
var yql_url = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql';
$.ajax({
    'url': yql_url,
    'data': {
        'q': 'SELECT * FROM json WHERE url="' + url + '"',
        'format': 'json',
        'jsonCompat': 'new'
    },
    'dataType': 'jsonp',
    'success': (function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        doSomethingWithThatData(data.query.results.json);
    })
});
};
```